# Who found the assassin's body in the 5th episode of the Mandalorian?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

At the end of the episode 5 of the Mandalorian some mysterious figure approaches the body of the dead assassin. It doesn't seem it was ever explained (even though the season ended), who that person was. Is there something I have missed, that explained who that was?

Answer (score 9):

Per Episode 14 (S3E6) it's actually

> Boba Fett, who saves Fennec Shand's life

Original answer below

<s>Based on Episode 8, I suspect it was</s>

> Moff Gideon

There's several reasons.

1. The assassin was formerly Imperial. We're never told who put the bounty on her head, but it's not unreasonable to assume it was someone in the Empire itself.
2. The person seems to know a lot about everything. Given that

> Gideon knew a lot about everyone with Mando in the bar, including Mando's real name

it's not unreasonable to assume this person would know where she was hiding, and thus where to find her corpse.
3. This character had not yet been introduced, so it would make sense to hide their face
4. This character wears black boots and a cape consistent with what we saw in Episode 5

[image: The mysterious figure]

Comment: There was a definite boot spur 'jingle-jangle' as the character approached the prone corpse. I don't recall any other scene with Moff Gideon where this sound accompanied him.

Comment: I agree with this, it makes the most sense.

Answer (score 7):

Currently, the identity of the character is unknown. However, a popular fan theory suggests it may be Boba Fett. This theory is based on a distinct sound effect used to punctuate the currently-unknown character's footsteps, the jingling of spurs generally heard in Western films. A similar sound effect was used in *The Empire Strikes Back* when Boba Fett was onscreen, as a reference to the bounty hunters and hired guns in Westerns such as Sergio Leone's Dollars Trilogy.

> "The sound of spurs jangling was added in the scene when Boba Fett enters next to Darth Vader in the Cloud City dining room in *The Empire Strikes Back*. According to the DVD commentary and numerous other sources, this was done to give the character a menacing aura in keeping with mid-20th-century western films." ([Boba Fett](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett/Legends#Behind_the_scenes))

Since Boba survived the Sarlacc Pit in Legends, it is possible that he did so in the current Canon continuity as well. However, this is purely fan speculation based on the sound effect and the use of Mandalorians as a main focus in the TV show (although it should be noted that according to the *Clone Wars* animated show, neither Boba nor Jango are considered to be legitimate Mandalorians).

Comment: But it is a well known fact that productions recycle sound effects to save effort and time, this could explain the sound.

Comment: Jango was a legitimate Mandolorian, he followed the creed

Comment: @Firestryke My answer is over a year old. Jango being recanonized as a legitimate Mando'ad happened less than a week ago.